# Carousel when i login into website is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

Carousel with buy and try products are placed in the website
But i login the jquery is not affecting to the carousel
Here are the errors

```
1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined 

2) Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://www.trynbuyindia.com/# from frame with URL https://www.youtube.com/embed/_sKw8edkBT4?enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.trynbuyindia.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

3)Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/_sKw8edkBT4?enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.trynbuyindia.com': 'ALLOWALL' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored. 

4)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js:1
Unable to post message to https://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin https://www.trynbuyindia.com.



// bottom carosel //
```

$(".botcarousel1").jCarouselLite({

```
btnNext: ".scrlright a",
btnPrev: ".scrlleft a",
visible: 2,
speed: 1200,
scroll: 1
```

});

```
// bottom carosel //
 $(".botcarousel2").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: ".scrlright1 a",
    btnPrev: ".scrlleft1 a",
    visible: 2,
    speed: 1200,
    scroll: 1
});
```

**Below is the view code**

```
<div class="botcarousel1">
          <ul>
               <?php  $nophoto  = theme_img('no_picture.png', lang('no_image_available'),130,130);
           foreach($featured_products as $product){ 
          if($product['product_type']==0)
          {
              ?>
            <li>
              <div class="prodbox">
                <div class="prodimg">
                     <a href="<?php echo base_url().$product['slug']; ?>"  title="<?php echo $product['name'];?>" >             

            <?php

            if(isset($product['images'])&&$product['images']<>'false'){
            $product['images']  =array_values((array)json_decode($product['images'])); 
            if(!empty($product['images'][0]))
            {
                $primary    = $product['images'][0];
                foreach($product['images'] as $photo)
                {
                    if(isset($photo->primary))
                    {
                        $primary    = $photo;
                    }
                }
                    $photo  = '<img class="pokemon" width="130" height="130" src="'.image_url().'images/small/'.$primary->filename.'" alt="'.$product['seo_title'].'"/>';
            }
            echo $photo;
            } else {
            echo $nophoto;
            }

                ?>
          </a>
                </div>
                <div class="prodname"><?php echo my_character_limiter($product['name'],15); ?></div>
                <?php   if($product['product_type']==1){ ?>
                <div class="hpricetag">
                <strike><?php echo format_currency1($product['price']); ?></strike> <span class="wcolor1"><?php echo format_currency1($product['saleprice']); ?></span> 
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="prodbuy">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $product['id']?>"/>
          <?php $available_quantity=$this->Product_model->get_available_quantity($product['id']);  

          if((bool)$product['track_stock']  && config_item('inventory_enabled')):?>
          <?php 
          $customer = $this->go_cart->customer();
          if(isset($customer['id'])&&$customer['id']<>''){ ?>
          <?php if($product['product_type']==0){ ?>
          <a href="javascript:;" class="add_to_cart" rel="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"> Try Now</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
          <!--<a href="javascript:;" class="add_to_cart" rel="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"> Buy Now</a>!-->
      <a href="<?php echo base_url().$product['slug']; ?>"  rel="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"> Buy Now</a>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
           <?php if($product['product_type']==0){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('authenticate/redirect/'.$product['id']); ?>" > Try Now</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url().$product['slug']; ?>"  rel="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"> Buy Now</a>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php else: ?>
           <?php if($product['product_type']==0){ ?>
           <span style="color:red;padding-left:10px;visibility:hidden;" >No TRYs available</span>
           <?php } else{ ?>
          <span style="color:red;padding-left:10px;visibility:hidden;" >Out of stock</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
           <?php } }
           ?>
          </ul>      
          </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone suggest me what is happening here !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The object where `offsetWidth` is there is empty.

Comment: Please provide a link or a JSFiddle

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for all these kinds of questions. Its very hard to speculate on these kinds of errors without looking at the source code

Comment: Do not link to your site. Provide code, please.

Comment: k i am giving the code

Comment: updated pls check it out